# Why isn't my rendered preview fully colored?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

[image]

My object is fully colored, but when I hit F12 to render a good portion of my object looks as if it's still in the viewport shading.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, and I'm also having a hard time finding someone that's had the same issue.

Comment: Looks like you have a hidden object that is only visible on render, check your outline and see the icoes that looks like an eye

Answer (score 0):

As Emir said, it's most likely a second, overlapping object that is invisible in the Viewport but still enabled in Renders. However, you need to look for the **Camera Icon** instead of an eye.

[image]

Comment: thank you both! It definitely was an overlap